# xmlstarlet always count 0

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet

In order to realize a script to import into my db, I would like to count the number of iteration of a node in an xml file.
I'm tried to use xmlstarlet, but each time he is returning 0 as answer...

Here is a sample of my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?> 
<global xmlns="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx">
     <place geoAccuracy="0" geoStatus="0" geoLatDeg="0.0" geoLongDeg="0.0" id="123">
         <name>XXXXXX</name>
         <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
         <city>city</city>
         <country>country</country>
     </place>
     <place geoAccuracy="0" geoStatus="0" geoLatDeg="0.0" geoLongDeg="0.0" id="123">
         <name>XXXXXX</name>
         <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
         <city>city</city>
         <country>country</country>
    </place>
```

In my bash, I did this :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="places.xml" RESULT=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//place)" $FILE)
echo $RESULT
```

Each time, it returns 0 as a result... I've tried different XPaths like "//global/place" or "/place" but the result is the same...

Does any one has any idea on how to resolve it ?
I'm a using an Ubuntu server 14.04LTS.

Comment: I think you forgot to translate your XPath so it says `place` instead of `lieu` (?)

Comment: That notwithstanding, maybe you have to specify some namespace mapping for xmlstarlet?

Comment: You're right... I did not translate in my presentation... I did the correction. But this mistake was not in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@O.R.Mapper is correct: You have to specify the namespace when using `xmlstarlet`:

```
 xmlstarlet sel -N q="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx" -t -v 'count(//q:place)' "$FILE"
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^
```

works for me (returns 2, provided I add `</global>` to the end of the test sample you provided).

The `q` is the name you will use to refer to the namespace, and the `http...x` is the `xmlns` value from your XML file.  Then each tag name has `q:` added to the front of it to specify the namespace.  Instead of `q`, you can use whatever ID you want to refer to the namespace — the URL is what defines the namespace, not the reference.

From [the docs](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html).

Comment: Thks a lot to both of you it runs perfectly !

Comment: A better doc link is http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html, which explains that `_:place` should work without having to bother with definitions on the command line.